# Do PlayStation 2 controllers support USB connections?

Tags: controllers, ps2

Does the classic PlayStation 2 controller support a USB standard?  I.E., can I cut the cable and solder a USB connector to it?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no.

Comment: I assume not, considering it doesn't use a USB connector

Comment: Having said that, PS3 controllers use the USB standard.

Comment: Have you considered getting a PS2->USB adapter?  I've owned a few like this - http://www.amazon.com/Trenro-Dual-PlayStation-Controller-Adapter-2/dp/B000F6BGXY  Also, PS3/PS4 controllers can be hooked up over USB or Bluetooth, with the right drivers.

Comment: Yeah, but not having electronic monies is a pain: Amazon doesn't take cash.

Comment: Step 1: Go to grocery store. Step 2: Buy amazon gift card. Step 3: Buy stuff on Amazon.  Step 4: Controllers, y'all!

Comment: @agent86 this is brilliance at its worst.  Brilliance at its best would involve more duct tape and paperclips, but this is good enough.  WHY DIDN'T I EVER THINK OF THIS???

Comment: I'm sure I could work some duct tape and some paperclips in there somewhere.  Blare the McGuyver theme in your car on the way over for maximum brilliance points.

Comment: Unfortunately I forgot to burn it to my MixCD collection (set of 6 discs - I have a lot of music)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly interfacing a PlayStation 2 controller to USB is a losing proposition.  The protocols and hardware are not at all compatible.  You're in for way too much work, risk, and pain.

You can, however, [buy a cheap adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001AATQ0Y) for just a couple of bucks.  These tend to be cheap both in terms of cost and in terms of reliability, so I suggest buying someplace with a good warranty/return policy.

Comment: I can confirm these adapters work. I just played some Guilty Gear X2 and it worked perfectly after setting up the mappings.

Answer (score 6):

You can not **simply** replace a PlayStation 2 controller connection with a USB connection, and expect it to work.

The immediate clue is in the wires. Not only do the data lines mis-match, but the power line for the controller uses 3.3 volts, and USB supplies 5 volts.

[image: PlayStation controller connector]

Simply connecting the controller to a powered USB slot could cause unsalvageable damage.

With specific knowledge and skill in electronics and the data being exchanged, it is definitely plausible. [There are guides online for doing so](http://store.curiousinventor.com/guides/PS2), but they can be are generally complex, and not for the layman.

Comment: Waiting for accept-timer to expire...

Comment: But thanks.  I'm considering getting a PS3 controller (probably not a PS4, I don't like wireless).  Or I may just bust out the old PS2 itself.

Comment: @Daniel PS3 controllers are also wireless.  However, both PS3 and PS4 controllers can be connected using a USB A to B-mini cable.  At least I think it's B-mini.

Comment: As a side note I need to figure out how to connect it to the internet (if that's possible of the PS2?)

Comment: Do you mean "unsalvageable damage"?

Comment: In my case it will be salvageable damage.  I can salvage SMD components and use them.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/262875/how-to-connect-playstation-2-to-internet-without-rj-45-port

Comment: The PS3 controller has a mini connection, and the PS4 controller has a micro connection. That said, from my own playing around, the PS3 either doesn't actually run input through the connection, or doesn't interface like any other controller. It is likely the ports are just for power, as they were intended. The Bluetooth standard **can** be easier to get connected, though I am mostly experienced with connecting to an Android device.

Comment: You can get hard wired controllers for the [ps3](https://www.gamesmen.com.au/cont-ps3-pc-ttx-wired-controller-black?gclid=Cj0KEQjw6My4BRD4ssKGvYvB-YsBEiQAJYd77USkvJMlsVLJHsEl5G0UvQBfoEMUySNLVKKBYLCgVGEaAmNs8P8HAQ) and the [ps4](http://www.amazon.com/Horipadfpsplus/dp/B0106XFCPI)

Comment: if so @Ben then let the community know because they seem to be n tears about not having wired controllers.

Comment: @Daniel which "community"?

Comment: The PlayStation forum on Sony.  Apparently there are several people complaining about their nonexistence.

Comment: @Daniel if you are already a member, I would advise you do it yourself, as I am not a member, or been on the forums before.

Comment: @Timelord64 There is a 3rd party driver for PS3 controller that creates correct button mapping on windows.By default Windows may try to detect it as a 360 controller or just ignore it all together (I've had both happen). It works both wired and over Bluetooth. Note that this makes windows recognize this as an Xbox gamepad and that games with gamepad support will refer to the buttons by the Xbox names. (X is A on the Xbox) Better DS3 [link](http://betterds3.ciebiera.net/)

Comment: It does send the data over the cable, you can use a PS3 controller with a PC which has no bluetooth. It also decreases latency to plug the controller into the PS3 with a cable. I used to be kind of semi-pro at COD back in the PS3 days and I always played with the cable in.