# How to connect Playstation 2 to internet without RJ-45 port

Tags: ps2

My PS2 doesn't have an ethernet jack on it.  How can I connect it to the internet so I can play TF2 (I've heard TF2 will run on the PS2)?

Comment: TF2 was released for PC, Xbox 360, and PS3.  No idea where you heard PS2.

Comment: The omniscient google - because they *can't put anything on the internet that isn't true...*

Comment: By "TF2" you're referring to "Team Fortress 2", right? If so, it was never released for PS2. As for your question: you'll need the [**Network Adaptor**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_2_Expansion_Bay#Network_Adaptor).

Comment: Anyways that's irrelevant to the question - I'll find something to do with it.

Comment: @Nolonar An Amazon link would be more helpful - already saw this page.

Comment: AND YES TEAM FORTRESS 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your PlayStation 2 does not have an Ethernet port as it does not have any **inbuilt** networking capabilities.

To network, you need a PlayStation 2 network adapter.

Your actual objective faces two much greater difficulties:

1. Team Fortress 2 was a PlayStation 3 title. It is not supported, on PlayStation 2.
2. Until recently, the only PlayStation 2 game that still had an online server was Final Fantasy. However, [in March, these servers were also shutdown](http://knowtechie.com/playstation-2-servers-shut-down-after-16-years/). There is literally no game server to connect to, even if you obtain an adapter and supported online game.

Comment: Well, COD3 is still online.  But I am sad that PS2 doesn't support TF2.  The youtube vid I saw the title for turned out to be fake (the guy was sitting on his PS2 and playing TF2 on his PS3 - lame)

Comment: @Daniel, could you show is proof of the COD servers being online? If you were not asking how to get online in the first place, I'd take your word for it, but it's been a big point of trivia in one of my friends circles that PS2 is "officially offline for good", so that is definitely relevant to my interests =)

Comment: The later slim PlayStation 2 models had built-in Ethernet ports. Getting a used slim PS2 would probably be a cheaper option than now hard to find network adapter.

Comment: @Ross Ridge, the point is, they can't go online, anyway

Comment: They can go LAN at a minimum.  Anyways, @Timelord64 I got that from the wikipedia page.  And you can fight it out with them #Thisismyspoon (wait - there is no spoon...)

Comment: @Daniel could you provide the link? It is possible that the page you are suggesting is old, therefore outdated. The information that Timelord is suggesting was announced only recently, and officially, within the last month or so.

Comment: @Daniel, it states that CoD is available online *with a workaround*. Technically, the same could be said about any other PS2 game, with a bit of networking knowledge. But if you find players using a workaround for a game you want to play, you can probably apply said method to connect to the server they use.